# Maximum entropy of a two-level system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, two-level-system

> Consider a 2-level system of $N$ particles with energies and degeneracies $g_0=1, g_1=2$, is there a way to demonstrate mathematically what is the maximum entropy?

Here’s my attempt:

Using Boltzmann entropy for formula $S=k_b\ln W$ , $W=\frac{N!2^n}{n!(N-n)!}$ and the Stirling approximation for factorials $\ln N! \approx N \ln N - N$:
$$S=k_b \left[ N \ln N + n \ln 2 - (N-n) \ln (N-n) - n \ln n \right]$$
and got stuck.

However, thinking about the maximum disorder, the answer is probably $n=\frac{2N}{3}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Then you need to find the maximum of your function:

$$ f(x) = x \ln{2} - (N - x) \ln{(N-x)} - x \ln{x} $$.

so:

$$f'(x) = 0 =\ln{(N-x)}-\ln{x}+\ln(2)$$,
$$ \ln\left( \frac{x}{N-x} \right)=\ln 2$$,
$$x=\frac{2N}{3}$$.
So your intuition was correct.